# Why does const char *foo = "Hello"; compile but not const int *foo = 5;?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

Correct me if I am wrong, but I had assumed this line of code:

```
const char *foo = "Hello";
```

Meant that an array of chars filled with "Hello" are created somewhere on the stack, and foo is a pointer to it. In that case, I don't understand why this line of code gives an "invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const int*'

```
const int *foo = 5;
```

Won't it just create an integer of 5 somewhere on the stack and have foo point to it?

Comment: `5` is an integer literal, it has type `int`. `"hello"` is a string literal, it has type `const char*`. So `int != int*`.

Comment: A const char* string like "Hello" will normally go on the heap, not on the stack.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage String literal like this doesn't go on the heap (nor stack) with most compilers. It will be embedded into binary as read-only data.

Comment: @DeiDei: No, the string literal `"hello"` is of type `char[6]` in C, `const char[6]` in C++. It is implicitly converted at compile time to `char*` in C,  `const char*` in C++.

Comment: The language *could* have provided a construct that yields the address of a statically allocated anonymous integer object with a specified value. It just wasn't considered to be as useful as string literals, which do essentially the same thing for character arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `"Hello"` is a [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) of type `char [N]` (in C) and `const char[N]` (in C++), which decays to a type `char*` (in C) or `const char*` (in C++), same as the pointer you are binding it to. On the other hand, `5` is a rvalue and its type is an `int`, so you cannot bind it to a pointer of type `const int*`.

You may find [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c) useful.

Comment: Why does it decay to const char*?

Comment: @Goldname Because those are the rules inherited from C. That's why you can pass arrays of chars to functions that take pointers of chars. The reason is that C (and subsequently C++) does not have copy semantics for arrays (for reasons of efficiency), and when you pass an array you effectively pass the pointer to its first element. Had it had copy semantics, then all arrays will be copied when passed by value, which is regarded as inefficient. You can use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (which is a thin wrapper around a C-style array) to pass arrays by value.

Comment: It's of type `char[6]` in C, `const char[6]` in C++. (The question has both tags.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks, I added it, didn't know that actually :) But I guess that's because `const` came later in C.

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance, you are using a **string literal** to initialize the value of foo.

In the first, foo itself is a constant pointer to char which is in some respects "special" compared to other pointers.

For most pointers, such as in your second example where you declare foo as a constant pointer to int, you *initialize* it to the ***address*** that you wish for the pointer to *point* to.

In other words, the following code:

```
const int *foo = 5;
```

Is wrong because you are telling the compiler that the address of foo is 5 when you really want to foo to point to the value of 5.

You can use the dereference operator to access the value stored in foo; what you want to say is this:

```
const int *foo = malloc(sizeof(int));
*foo = 5;
```

String literals are a special case: they are treated specially because C represents strings as arrays of characters terminated by '\0'.

```
const char *foo = "Hello";
```

Sets the address of foo to point at the letter 'H' in "Hello\0". All string literals used in this manner are stored in a special section of memory that tends to be read-only; trying to modify foo like this:

```
foo[0] = 'W';
```

Will result in undefined behavior.

The special behavior of string literals in an initialization context is related to the way that arrays occassionally decay into pointers; when an array is assigned to a pointer by =, you are really stating that you want the pointer to *point to* the first element of the given array.

One last note:

You could *force* the compiler to interpret the 5 as a memory address using a cast:

```
// In C:
const int *foo = (const int*) 5;
// In C++:
const int *foo = reinterpret_cast<const int *>(5);
```

But, your program will likely crash because whatever is stored at memory location 5 is likely inaccessible by your program.

Answer (score 0):

```
//  const char* c = 5;
//  const char* c = '5';
//  const int*  i = 7;
```

the three lines above will generate a compile time error as long as there's no accepted conversion. so c expects a literal string and you pass a single character or integer value.

this is like what happen in strcmp when passing to it a single char not a string:

```
char* name = "name";
char  c = 'a'; 

if(strcmp(c, name));// error cannot convert first parameter from char to const char*
```